# Using MARTE GQAM stereotypes in Papyrus UML models

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

I am trying to stereotype some elements of my model with the MARTE GQAM stereotypes but I am having troubles in assigning values to some of their properties. For instance I have stereotyped a message between two lifelines as <>. I would like to assign a value to its hostDemand property which shall be a NFP_Duration instance. 
I can't see how to use the Papyrus editor to create a NFP_Duration instance and assign it to the hostDemand property.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Topcased 5.3.1 and Modelio 3.1.1, I just added these duration as Strings...