# How to assign NFP values to properties of MARTE stereotypes in Papyrus UML models

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

I've stereotyped an element of my model as MARTE::MARTE_DesignModel::HRM::HwLogical::HwComputing::HwProcessor. However, I do not understand how to specify its operating frequency with Papyrus. This property should be a NFP_Frequency instance, but  I can't see how to use the Papyrus editor to create a NFP_Frequency instance and assign it to the 'frequency' property.

There is another question similar to this on SO: [Using MARTE GQAM stereotypes in Papyrus UML models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841748/using-marte-gqam-stereotypes-in-papyrus-uml-models). However, there are no answers. Can someone shed some light on this?

Thank you in advance

--
Matteo

Answer (score 0):

If I am right the operating frequency should be an Interval so for that you have many possibilities depending of the used tool...

I am using Topcased 5.3.1 and Modelio 3.1 and both tools only allow me to set String as value of op_frequency so I would specified something like [freq1 .. freq2].

Under other modelling tool I guess that you should be able to refer to UML Interval with two Instance (one for the min and the other one with the max).

Hoping it helps,

EBR

Comment: Hi, you are referring to the 'op_Frequencies' attribute, that is indeed an Interval of NFP_Frequency instances. The 'frequency' property is in fact one single instance of NFP_Frequency data type. It has the attribute 'unit' of type FrequencyUnitKind and it inherits from NFP_Real, so it has also the attribute 'value' of type Real. How do you specify a frequency of 1.5 GHz in Topcased using strings? Does this means that you have defined your own syntax? I cannot believe that this is _the_ way to model this thing...

Comment: In theory for specifying a frequency of 1,5 GHz I would use a Literal Unlimited Natural but in real worl the Topcased and Modelio allow me to use String. Maybe it is different for other tools...